# Onclick function malfunction

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I've got a button with an `onclick` function that is being used to upload a name and an image to my sql db. The problem is that it's not always working. Most of the times I've got to try multiple times in order to succeed.

Here's my form and function:

```js
function uploadImg(file) {
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  var url = "receitas2.php?op=2&nome=" + nome;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fd = new FormData();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      if (parseInt(res['val']) == 1) {
        alert(res['msg']);
        loadList();
      } else {
        alert(res['msg']);
      }
    }
  };
  fd.append('file0', file[0]);
  //fd.append('file', file);
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-material">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">Nome</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da receita" id="nome" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-12">Imagem</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input class="form-control form-control-line" type="file" id="upload" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick='uploadImg(document.getElementById("upload").files)'>Registar Receita</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason to use vanilla JS, when you already have bootstrap (so most likely also jQuery) included? Also: Any error messages so far? Your XHR-request is lacking any error handler afaik.

Comment: I think I found the problem. When in developer mode (the windows is resized ofc) it works fine. Might this be a signal that I need to use a settimeout? Where?

Comment: It's hard to debug without any knowledge about the backend. Check the logs there and check the network tab in your dev tools for the failed requests (and see if there is any indication what went wrong),

Comment: The problem seems to be in the frontend. The problem happens 90% of the times when Im with dev tools closed. With dev tools closed, the browser window is narrower and it barely happens. I suspect this has to do with file dimensions and load timings...